# Grails: Error initializing classpath: null

Tags: java, grails, null, classpath

I have two computer (work and home) both with:

Debian Bookworm (testing)

$ grails --version

| Grails Version: 5.2.0

| JVM Version: 11.0.15

JAVA_HOME, JDK_HOME and JRE_HOME are set.
GRAILS_HOME is set and in the PATH

Trying to run a freshly created Grails application on the computer at work I'm getting a nasty stacktrace:

```
$ grails create-app v5_2_0
| Application created at .../v5_2_0
$ cd v5_2_0
$ grails run-app --stacktrace --verbose
| Error Error initializing classpath: null
java.net.SocketTimeoutException
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector.tryConnect(TcpOutgoingConnector.java:81)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector.connect(TcpOutgoingConnector.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connectToDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:274)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connectToDaemonWithId(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:260)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.doStartDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:227)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:216)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:138)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:144)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:98)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:222)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.runClientAction(ProviderConnection.java:168)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:158)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:234)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterizedActionRunner.execute(ParameterizedActionRunner.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableActionRunner.run(CancellableActionRunner.java:52)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:69)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.run(ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.java:56)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:144)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
| Error Error initializing classpath: null
```

On the similar installed home computer all is running well.

My first impression is that the first computer has somehow a problem with the java installation, but I don't know what.

- in the app directory the subdirectory .gradle won't be created
- deleting ~/.gradle and ~/.m2 doesn't help
- - trying run-app again creates ~/.gradle (not with all subdirectories), but no ~/.m2
- grails clean brings up the same error

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 0):

Due to whatever reason the rule accepting connections on my loopback interface has disappeared from my iptables INPUT chain. So gradle couldn't connect to it.
The merit to this unexpected discovery goes to [Stefan Oehme](https://github.com/oehme) for [this answer](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/cannot-create-or-import-any-gradle-project/19853/5)

Thank you Stefan!

BTW, as auxiliary bonus, this was the same reason, why grovvyConsole took aeons to show up (although it did). grovvyConsole seems to also try to bind to the loopback interface.